# How can I position subviews using text baseline alignments in a custom SwiftUI Layout?

Tags: swiftui

Following the [WWDC sample code](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/) I have written a custom `HStack` layout that ensures all of the contents have equal widths. This works fine, and I can make my contents line up with center, top and bottom alignments, but I can't figure out how to position the subviews using the first or last text baseline alignments. There doesn't seem to be anything available in a `LayoutSubview` that would offer up a baseline position for me to use in `placeSubviews`.

Here is my current implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EqualHStack: Layout {
    
    static var layoutProperties: LayoutProperties {
        var properties = LayoutProperties()
        properties.stackOrientation = .horizontal
        return properties
    }
        
    var alignment = VerticalAlignment.center
    var spacing: CGFloat?
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let totalSpacing = spacing.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        return CGSize(
            width: maxSize.width * CGFloat(subviews.count) + totalSpacing,
            height: maxSize.height
        )
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let subProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height)
        var x = bounds.minX + (maxSize.width / 2)
        let y: CGFloat
        let anchor: UnitPoint
        switch alignment {
        case .top:
            y = bounds.minY
            anchor = .top
        case .center:
            y = bounds.midY
            anchor = .center
        case .bottom:
            y = bounds.maxY
            anchor = .bottom
        default:
            y = bounds.midY
            anchor = .center
            print("I don't know how to get baseline alignment in custom layouts")
        }
        for (subview, spacing) in zip(subviews, spacing) {
            subview.place(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), anchor: anchor, proposal: subProposal)
            x += maxSize.width + spacing
        }
    }
        
    private func maxSize(subviews: Subviews) -> CGSize {
        let subviewSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        let maxSize = subviewSizes.reduce(CGSize.zero) { currentMax, subview in
            CGSize(
                width: max(currentMax.width, subview.width),
                height: max(currentMax.height, subview.height))
        }
        return maxSize
    }
    
    private func spacing(subviews: Subviews) -> [CGFloat] {
        subviews.indices.map { index in
            guard index < subviews.count - 1 else { return 0 }
            if let spacing {
                return spacing
            }
            return subviews[index].spacing.distance(to: subviews[index + 1].spacing, along: .horizontal)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VStack {
        EqualHStack {
            Text("Item 1\nSecond Line")
            Text("Item twoooo")
            Text("I3")
        }
        EqualHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
            Text("Item 1\nSecond Line")
            Text("Item twoooo")
            Text("I3")
        }
        EqualHStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("Item 1\nSecond Line")
            Text("Item twoooo")
            Text("I3")
        }
        EqualHStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("Item 1\nSecond Line")
            Text("Item twoooo")
            Text("I3")
        }
        EqualHStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
            Text("Item 1\nSecond Line")
            Text("Item twoooo")
            Text("I3")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I calculate the y position for placing subviews so that the baseline alignment is respected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time but I think I got it.

You can't access the baseline offset globally for the whole view, but you can do for the single subviews – which makes sense because each text subview could have a different baseline offset depending on font size.

Strangely you access it through a method on the single subview AND a [subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewdimensions/subscript(_:)-7dtda) (who would have guessed :)
`baselineOffset = subview.dimensions(in: proposal)[.firstTextBaseline]`
or
`baselineOffset = subview.dimensions(in: proposal)[.lastTextBaseline]`

So you also have to apply the single baseline offsets during the loop over the subviews and level them with the overall maximum baseline offset. Be sure only to apply the offsets if the alignment is of that kind ;)

[image]

```
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let subProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height)

        var x = bounds.minX + (maxSize.width / 2)
        let y: CGFloat
        let anchor: UnitPoint
        switch alignment {
        case .top:
            y = bounds.minY
            anchor = .top
        case .center:
            y = bounds.midY
            anchor = .center
        case .bottom:
            y = bounds.maxY
            anchor = .bottom
        case .firstTextBaseline:
            y = bounds.minY
            anchor = .top
        case .lastTextBaseline:
            y = bounds.minY
            anchor = .top
        default:
            y = bounds.midY
            anchor = .center
        }
        // find maximum baseline offset based on alignment
        var maxOffset = subviews.reduce (0.0) { max($0, $1.dimensions(in: proposal)[alignment]) }

        for (subview, spacing) in zip(subviews, spacing) {
            
            let baselineOffset: CGFloat
            switch alignment {
            case .firstTextBaseline:
                baselineOffset = subview.dimensions(in: proposal)[.firstTextBaseline]
            case .lastTextBaseline:
                baselineOffset = subview.dimensions(in: proposal)[.lastTextBaseline]
            default:
                baselineOffset = 0
                maxOffset = 0 // reset maxOffset, because not needed
            }

            subview.place(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: y - baselineOffset + maxOffset), anchor: anchor, proposal: subProposal) // changed the anchor to .topleading always!
            x += maxSize.width + spacing
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah! The dimensions  / subscript was what I was missing. Thanks!